# Less Guard not working as expected

Tags: css, less

I have a mixin that has a guard clause.

I've followed the guide and believe the syntax below to be correct.

Essentially the guide should ensure that @palette is one of a range of custom colors, and @color a number from a set.

This works - it compiles and produces the correct output.

However, if I change the @palette variable to cause a fault, Less doesn't compile - is this the expected behaviour?

```
.AccentPalette(@palette; @color:500) when
    (@palette = amber), (@palette = blue), (@palette = blueGrey), (@palette = cyan), (@palette = deepOrange),
    (@palette = deepPurple), (@palette = green), (@palette = grey), (@palette = indigo), (@palette = lightBlue),
    (@palette = lightGreen), (@palette = lime), (@palette = orange), (@palette = pink), (@palette = purple),
    (@palette = red), (@palette = teal), (@palette = yellow) and
    (@color = 50), (@color = 100), (@color = 200), (@color = 300), (@color = 400),
    (@color = 500), (@color = 600), (@color = 700), (@color = 800), (@color = 900) {
    .Swatch(@palette); 

    @accentColor:"@{@{color}}";

    @accent50:  @50; 
    @accent100: @100; 
    @accent200: @200; 
    @accent300: @300; 
    @accent400: @400; 
    @accent500: @500; 
    @accent600: @600; 
    @accent700: @700; 
    @accent800: @800; 
    @accent900: @900;
}
```

Called like this:

```
.AccentPalette(indigo);
```

A swatch example - there are a number of them, one for each color.

```
.Swatch(amber)
{
    @50: #fff8e1;
    @100:#ffecb3;
    @200:#ffe082;
    @300:#ffd54f;
    @400:#ffca28;
    @500:#ffc107;
    @600:#ffb300;
    @700:#ffa000;
    @800:#ff8f00;
    @900:#ff6f00;
}
```

Comment: What error do you receive, when *Less doesn't compile*?

Comment: It's not very informative, it just gives me a -1, which it does every other time it doesn't compile. I'm using ServiceStack Bundler to integrate into an asp.net website.

Comment: The code you've posted here shouldn't cause compiler error if the 50-900 variables are declared. The problem might be with the `.Swatch(...)`, can you include that mixin's code also in the question?

Comment: @Harry - I've added a swatch example. There are examples for each of the colours in the palette variable.

Comment: @JohnOhara: By *cause a fault* you mean using a color which is not in the guard right? A bit confused because indigo does exist in the guard.

Comment: Hello @JohnOhara. Did that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what I said in my earlier comment, the problem is actually with the `.AccentPalette` mixin guard. It seems like the Less compiler evaluates the `and` before the `,` (or). Because of it, the guard always gets matched when you don't provide any value for the `@color` variable as the guard `@color = 500` is always true.

Consider the below simplified example:

```css
@500: dummy;
.AccentPalette(@palette; @color:500) when
(@palette = amber), (@palette = blue) and
(@color = 50), (@color = 500), (@color = 900) {
  .Swatch(@palette); 
  accentColor:"@{@{color}}";
}

.Swatch(amber){}
.Swatch(blue){}

#demo {
  .AccentPalette(amber;1000);
}
```

The compiler seems to evaluate it as follows: (note the extra pair of braces)

`(@palette = amber), ((@palette = blue) and (@color = 50)), (@color = 500), (@color = 900)`

This evaluates to `(false, (false and false), true, false)` or `(false, false, true, false`), so the mixin is always matched as there is one `true`.

---

The proper fix would've been to write the mixin guard as follows:

`((@palette = amber),(@palette = blue)) and ((@color = 50),(@color = 500),(@color = 900))`

but the Less compiler doesn't seem to like the extra pair of braces and gives a compiler error. So, the only option seems to be to split the guards into two levels like in the below example.

```css
@500: dummy;

.AccentPalette(@palette; @color:500) when (@palette = amber), (@palette = blue) {
  & when (@color = 50), (@color = 500), (@color = 900) {
    .Swatch(@palette); 
    accentColor:"@{@{color}}";
  }
}

.Swatch(amber){}
.Swatch(blue){}

#demo {
  .AccentPalette(red);
}
```